# C: fread does not read the full block

Tags: c, fopen, fread, fseek, uint16

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define N_DET 432
#define N_PROJ 500

int readSinogram(uint16_t mess[],char filename[], int sample){
    //init
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    //open file
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    //read sinogram
    fseek(fp,sizeof(uint16_t)*N_DET*N_PROJ*sample*2,SEEK_SET); //move pointer
    fread(mess,sizeof(uint16_t),N_DET*N_PROJ,fp); //read sinogram
    return 0;
};


int main()
{
    uint16_t mess[N_DET*N_PROJ];
    char filename[]="C:\\Path\\MyFile.fxc";
    double curr;
    int i,DET,PROJ;

    readSinogram(mess,filename,0); //read the data

    printf("\nDET?"); //ask for input
    scanf("%u", &DET);
    printf("\nPROJ?");
    scanf("%u", &PROJ);

    curr=mess[DET+N_DET*PROJ]; //get the data
    printf("Data: %f",curr); //print the data

    return 0;
}
```

This reads in the .fxc file, which is just a binary file containing uint16_t formatted numbers. "readSinogram" reads one data set which contains N_DET*N_PROJ numbers. (The pointer is moved by twice the block size, because there are alternating blocks of two measurements in the file.)
After reading it, one can put in a DET and PROJ and have a look at the data at this point.

So far, everything works fine. The data is correct for a certain data range but when asking for too big DET and/or PROJ the data is incorrect.
I do have the same file read in in Matlab and can confirm that the data in it is fine.

To be more exact: every index above [DET+N_DET*PROJ] > 248835 will return 52428 instead of the correct value (ranging from 0 to 4088). The values up to those work fine. So there's got to be something wrong with the "mess" array above that index, I guess.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're reading from a binary file with mode `"r"` and not `"rb"`.

Comment: Mode `"r"` is synonymous with mode `"rb"` on most platforms other than Windows.  Nevertheless, it's good form to specify `"rb"` when the data are not known or assumed to be text.  It doesn't sound like that's related to your problem, though.

Comment: sizeof(int) ? your defines default to int so if your sizeof(in) is 16 you may want to change them values to long int using suffix L

Comment: You declare `DET` and `PROJ` as type `int`, but use edit descriptor `%u` (for `unsigned int`) to scan them.  Probably this does not explain your issue either, but it's nevertheless an error.

Comment: You do not test the return value of `fread()` to verify that the full read request was satisfied.

Comment: The call to `fseek` doesn't do anything since the value of `sample` is `0` in the call to the function.

Comment: Using "rb" instead of "r" solved the issue, thanks! I totaly missed that part on the fopen reference page.

Comment: @John Bollinger: the line `char filename[]="C:\\Path\\MyFile.fxc";` was a big hint that the platform be MS/DOS or Windows.  Incidentally, one can use forward slashes in these platforms in place of backslashes.  Dominic should try `char filename[]="C:/Path/MyFile.fxc";` just for fun and education.

Comment: `N_DET ` is defined to be 432 `N_PROJ` is 500 so the maths leads to 432*500 = 216000 elements, thus your array can hold 216000 uint16_t values now if the index of the array is  `mess[DET+N_DET*PROJ] > 248835` you are certainly out of range of your allocated array which would lead to undefined behaviour and cause some mess. Please increase the array size

Comment: you also need error handling in `fopen` `fseek` and check the return for `fread` plus optionally you can close the opend file discriptor by `close(fd)`

Answer (score 1):

you need allocate a larger array to get to index value greater than 248835
currently you have the following defines

```
#define N_DET 432
#define N_PROJ 500
```

which leads to the array size of `432*500 = 216000`

now if your indexing the array at value **248835** `248835 > 216000` you would cause to access the memory out of the allocated memory for the array which would lead to **undefined behavior**. What you need is a bigger size array which can accommodate more than 248835 entries. a simple `#define N_DET 500` would do that, but you have to make sure that is the requirement. A basic index check would be helpful to avoid having a out of range problem something on the lines of

```
#define MAX_RANGE 500*500
if((DET+N_DET*PROJ) < MAX_RANGE)
    curr=mess[DET+N_DET*PROJ]; //get the data
else
   //error handling
```

you also need error handling in `fopen` `fseek` and check the return for `fread` plus optionally you can close the opened file discriptor by `close(fd)`

Comment: That is correct, of course. I did not do the math correctly when writing the question. I accidently calculated `[DET+N_PROJ*PROJ]` when getting the last possible index for posting here.
As allready mentioned, changing fopen mode to 'rb' did solve the issue. I do some error checking with the return values, I just shortened the code to post here. Thanks, anyways!